# Work with Azure Redis Cache (Preview) in Development

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-compute-emulator, azure-redis-cache

Is it possible to work with Azure Redis Cache (Preview) on some emulator as with Azure Storages?

From this post [Possible to run Azure Caching Preview without emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005495/possible-to-run-azure-caching-preview-without-emulator) i guess it's possible with devfabric emulator but how configure it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Redis Cache is not part of the local development Azure Emulator tooling. The StackOverflow entry you're referring to is for the 'other' caching technology Azure provides (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg278356.aspx for details and differences).

As Azure Redis Cache service is just a hosted Redis instance, you can or should simply run a local Redis for Windows instance (see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/04/lap-around-azure-redis-cache-preview/).

Comment: so if i run redis-server and redis-client local it can be as "emulator" for Azure Redis Cache? Wright?

Comment: Yep exactly - there's a good Redis .Net Client available from the StackOverflow devs themselves, see Scott Hanselmann's blog post for a brief explanation: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TryingRedisCachingAsAServiceOnWindowsAzure.aspx .

Comment: and when i will create connection to redis like `ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("contoso5.redis.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=... ");` i need to add local ip to connection?

Comment: Again.. yep. What I personally do is store these two different connection strings in a local/azure config using the "Windows Azure Configuration Manager" (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/) so it automatically picks the correct conenction string depending on where I run it.. locally or on azure. Works like a charm.